# Mongo Java finding Maching record in mongo array

Tags: java, mongodb

My sample doc is

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("51f89c1484ae3aa758ad56e9"),
    "group_name" : "Operator",
    "privileges" : [
        "Add Group",
        "Edit/Delete Group",
        "Add User",
        "Edit/Delete User",
        "Log History",
        "Add Stopwords Group",
        "Edit/Delete Stopwords Group",
        "Add Stopwords",
        "Edit/Delete Stopwords",
        "Recomended Stopwords"
    ],
    "users" : [
        {
            "full_name" : "operator1",
            "user_name" : "operator",
            "password" : "pass$123",
            "status" : "Active"
        },
        {
            "full_name" : "Sumit Dshpande",
            "user_name" : "dsumit",
            "password" : "pass$123",
            "status" : "Active"
        }
    ]
}
```

I am trying to match user_name and password in users array entered by user.

My java code is :

```
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
List<BasicDBObject> parts = new ArrayList<BasicDBObject>();
parts.add(new BasicDBObject("users.user_name", uname));
parts.add(new BasicDBObject("users.password", password));
query.put("$and", parts);

DBCursor cursor = collection.find(query);
while (cursor.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(cursor.next());
}
```

But it returns all users in matching array.I want users under group so that I can change group privileges. 
 Is this right approach for schema designing in nosql.

Comment: Could you give an example of the expected output?

Comment: If you change group privileges, it will change it for the entire group. In that case why do you want specific users with username and password? looks like there is something wrong in how you have structured your collections, please add more info about what you need

Answer (score 0):

We would need to get holistic information about your application in order to tell you if you're making the right modeling decisions; however, I can help you with your current query.

In order to match multiple attributes within the same element of an array, you should use the $elemMatch operator (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/projection/elemMatch/).

eg)

```js
collection.find({users:{$elemMatch:{username:uname,password:password}}});
```